Need to get for each document some info from all containing collections
Collection House:
{
    "_id": ObjectId('0001'),
    "fruit": "apple",
    "entries": [
        DBRef('room', ObjectId('1234')),
        DBRef('room', ObjectId('5678'))
    ]
}

Collection rooms:
{
    "_id": ObjectId('1234'),
    "some": "data"
}

I now want all the rooms normal output (simple find) BUT enriched with a fruit array containing all fruits of houses that contain the rooms (array because a room could be in multiple houses) like:
[
    {
        "some": "data",
        "fruits": ["apple"]
    }
]

So I tried aggregating on rooms, doing a lookup on the house, but as I need to search the array, I could not use a normal lookup but one with pipeline. Within the pipeline I would need to create some match-making BUT within that (using map) I cannot get the damn ObjectId out of the DBRef. I know, DBRef is apparently outdated but it's the DB we have now and I need to work with.
Any help? DB is on version 4.0.22

Consider refactoring your schema to denormalize the house entries as array entries of rooms if possible for your specific query. Also, avoid using DBRef. Currently, just use a sub-pipeline to do a $lookup like this

@ray as I said, this is a productive database we need to work with for now. We will refactor it but we still need to get stuff done, so I need an answer unfortunately

1. It's unclear what you mean by "I know want all the rooms with a fruit array (because a room could be in multiple houses)". Do you mean entries array instead of fruit array?  2. Wrt "So I tried aggregating on rooms, doing a lookup on the house" Show what you have tried. 3. Edit your post and add usable example data which matches the pipeline you tried.

@aneroid 1. Yeah, phrased badly. I want some output of rooms (like with simple find) enriched with an array called fruits (created through the operation) which shall contain the fruits of all houses which contain my room. Clearer? 2./3. My attempts lead to nothing close of a good result, I don’t think they would be helpful at all. Example output is the third snippet, it’s exactly what I need

But I will add it later, right now no access to the computer where it’s on… it’s basically just a simple join operation, did not imagine it would be so hard in Mongo

@aneroid Posted the "solution" as answer. But it's not a solution because aggregate cannot work with DBRef and this breaks it for me... damn it

@IceFire It's good you posted your current "alternative" as an answer because I was doing the lookup the other way round.

When the example data is inserted with insertMany(), the object with fields { $ref: ..., $id: ... } get inserted as DBRef objects anyway (image below). And the aggregation pipeline you've provided in your answer works in MongoDB 5/6/7, and possibly 4.3.3 onwards.
So it's an issue with "DB is on version 4.0.22" rather than "does not work with DBRef".
Workaround: Since you can't access $-prefixed fields in Mongo 4.0.22, use the technique from this StackOverflow answer (that answer deserves an upvote!)
1. Map each DBRef object to an array, so each room becomes an array of

{ k: <field_name>, v: <field_value> } objects
{
  "rooms": [
    [
      { "k": "$ref", "v": "rooms" },
      { "k": "$id", "v": { "$oid": "2bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd" } }
    ],
    [
      { "k": "$ref", "v": "rooms" },
      { "k": "$id", "v": { "$oid":  "3bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd" } }
    ]
  ]
}


Note that the $ref field is always the 1st object (index 0) in the array and $id is always the 2nd (index 1).

If $db existed, it would be the 3rd.

Here's the single demo-stage to do and Mongo Playground:
db.houses.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      rooms: {
        $map: {
          input: "$rooms",
          as: "room",
          in: { $objectToArray: "$$room" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])



2. Re-add those fields Map that 2nd value $id (index 1) to a field you can lookup, with a non-$-name:

Single-demo stage & playground:
db.houses.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      rooms: {
        $map: {
          input: "$rooms",
          as: "room",
          in: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $objectToArray: "$$room" }, 1] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])



3. Use that as the pipeline in your rooms aggregation $lookup stage and match each room's id with "$rooms.v":
db.rooms.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "houses",
      let: { room_id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            rooms: {
              $map: {
                input: "$rooms",
                as: "room",
                in: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $objectToArray: "$$room" }, 1] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ["$$room_id", "$rooms.v"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            a: "$fruit"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "houseFruits"
    }
  }
])

Final Mongo Playground working MongoDB 4.0.22

Edit: Btw, once you upgrade to at least MongoDB 5.0, then using the $lookup Correlated Subqueries Using Concise Syntax, this is what the full aggregation can be simplified to:
db.rooms.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "houses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "rooms.$id",
      pipeline: [
        { $project: { a: "$fruit" } }
      ],
      as: "houseFruits"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground for 5.0 onwards.

Example data inserted with DBRef objects:


Sweeeet! I was more complicated in my (working) solution even with DBRef for some reason. Your answer is better, thank you!

@IceFire And once you do upgrade to at least 5.0, see my edit for how small/simple the pipeline would be, even with DBRefs :-)

Intriguing! Thanks so much, I’ll make us upgrade for sure

Playground with the "actual" solution:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/HUm05wtOsMJ
Data:
db={
  "houses": [
    {
      "_id": 1001,
      "fruit": "apple",
      "dummy": "ignoreMe",
      "rooms": [
        {
          $ref: "rooms",
          $id: ObjectId("1bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd")
        },
        {
          $ref: "rooms",
          $id: ObjectId("2bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd")
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 1002,
      "fruit": "pear",
      "dummy": "ignoreMe",
      "rooms": [
        {
          $ref: "rooms",
          $id: ObjectId("2bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd")
        },
        {
          $ref: "rooms",
          $id: ObjectId("3bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd")
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rooms": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("1bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd"),
      "description": "room 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("2bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd"),
      "description": "room 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("3bcdefbcdefbcdefbcdefbcd"),
      "description": "room 3"
    }
  ]
}

Query:
db.rooms.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "houses",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$id",
                {
                  $map: {
                    "input": "$rooms",
                    "as": "room",
                    "in": "$$room.$id"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            a: "$fruit"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "houseFruits"
    }
  }
])

However, it does not work in my real-life example because "aggregation" does not work with "DBRef"... What it tells as error is that "fieldNames" may not contain "$"... Yeah, thanks for nothing. Apparently mapReduce needs to be used then.
And we need to refactor this DB.
